# Dynamically find all matching nodes from nested json arrays

Tags: java, json

I'm using Java and Jaxson primarily.

Assume a json structure such as

```
{
    "a" : "aVal",
    "b" : "bVal",
    "x" : [{
        "xCol1" :"x1_1",
        "xCol2" :"x1_2",
        "y" : [{
            "yCol1" : "x1_y1_1",
            "yCol2" : "x1_y1_2",
        },{
            "yCol1" : "x1_y2_1",
            "yCol2" : "x1_y2_2"
        }]
    },{
        "xCol1" :"x2_1",
        "xCol2" :"x2_2",
        "y" : [{
            "yCol1" : "x2_y1_1",
            "yCol2" : "x2_y1_2",
        },{
            "yCol1" : "x2_y2_1",
            "yCol2" : "x2_y2_2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Also assume a spec that tells us which node(s) to look for, say `x/y/yCol1`. Both width and depth of json can be greater than what is shown here: we don't know either the json or the specification beforehand: it must be processed dynamically.

The following works to do this recursively, but doesn't seem elegant...

```
public static void getPaths(String cp, String rp, JsonNode cj, List<String> rsp) {
    if (rp.indexOf("/", 0) == 1 ) {
        rsp.add(rp);
    } else {
        Integer ix = rp.indexOf("/", 1);
        String ncp = cp;
        String nrp = rp;
        if (ix > 0) {
            ncp = rp.substring(0, ix);
            nrp = rp.substring(ix);
        } else {
            ncp = rp;
        }
        JsonNode nn = cj.at(ncp);
        if (nn.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.ARRAY) {
            Integer i = 0;
            for (JsonNode j : ((ArrayNode)nn)) {
                getMatchingPaths(cp + ncp + "/" + i.toString(), nrp, j, rsp);
                i++;
            }
        } else if (nn.getNodeType() != JsonNodeType.MISSING) {
            rsp.add(cp + rp);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically:

- `cp` is the current path so far (outside caller pass in empty string)
- `rp` is the remaining path (outside caller pass in the whole path)
- `cj` is the current Node (outside caller pass in root node)
- `rsp` is
  the results (outside caller pass in an empty list)

So for the given example, the caller would turn the json string into jsonNode, create rspList as an empty list of string, and call `getPaths("", "/x/y/yCol1", jsonNode, rspList)`. The resulting response list is:

```
/x/0/y/0/yCol1
/x/0/y/1/yCol1
/x/1/y/0/yCol1
/x/1/y/1/yCol1
```

This is good enough for me to loop through, find each node using `at` and do whatever I want (such as derive new fields adjacent to the found fields). But I wonder if there are more elegant approaches using jaxson tricks or streaming tricks.

Comment: Maybe you could use JsonPath for that...

Comment: You may try [Josson](https://github.com/octomix/josson).  To look for the flattened keys of `x/y/yCol1`, use _Josson_ function `getNode` with this statement `map(x.map(y.map(yCol1))).flatten('/').keys().prepend('/')`.